# How to implement intent(?) on windows 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, protocol-handler

I see some features on windows 10 that are a copy of [Android intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) concept.

For example, when opening games, they open the Xbox programs by triggering an event `ms-gamingoverlay`. The flow have a windows native UI to select the application to be used, or search for one at the proprietary-application-store.

What exactly are those called in windows development literature?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-protocol

Comment: so `ms-gamingoverlay` et al is a protocol handler plain and simple? `ms-gamingoverlay://`?